# How does material-table know which rows are selected?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using [material-table](https://material-table.com/) in a project. I am trying to understand how the table knows which rows are selected and any possible way to access and modify that data.
[Here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection) are some example implementations of the selection feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the answer myself on the material-table github repo.
It turns out that each rowData will have an object "**tableData**" attached to it, which will store parameters such as id, checked, etc,.

So if the checked parameter is set to true, that row is selected, else not.